# Using moment to define time in an UTC-based cloud server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, momentjs

My application heavily relines on time being on pacific time
If I deploy my application on Google App Engine (US-WEST region), the time that is calculated by the cloud app engine is different than my local machine.

I've tried using Moment-Timezone to make it force the cloud server machine to use los angeles time format however its still giving me a different time than my local machine.

Is there a way to use moment so that the time values are consistent no matter where its deployed? Or did I implement the moment-time zone incorrectly?

```
const test = moment(new Date(filteredTimeLeft))
const endTime = test.tz('America/Los_Angeles').unix();
console.log('endTime', endTime)
const convertSec = Number(coin.seconds);
console.log('convertSec', convertSec)
const newDate = moment(new Date())
const calcTime = endTime - convertSec - newDate.tz('America/Los_Angeles').unix();
```

Comment: `.unix()` uses UTC, so you are overwriting your timezone conversion. Is that intended?

Comment: wait so why is new Date different from my local dev environmenet and the cloud server?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you came with usin the plain JS `new Date` along with moment, nor the use of `unix()`.

And I don't know what `coin.seconds` can be...

Anyway, here an example showing

- the plain JS date
- the UTC time
- your local time
- the Los Angeles time
- the New York time

```js
let js_date = new Date();
console.log("Plain JS date", js_date);

let moment_UTC = moment().utc();
console.log("UTC time", moment_UTC.format("hh:mm:ss"));

let moment_local = moment();
console.log("Your local time", moment_local.format("hh:mm:ss"));

let moment_Los_Angeles = moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles');
console.log("Los Angeles", moment_Los_Angeles.format("hh:mm:ss"));

let moment_New_York = moment().tz('America/New_York');
console.log("New York", moment_New_York.format("hh:mm:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```